# PySpark Dataframe cast two columns into new column of tuples based value of a third column

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, reduce, transpose

As the subject describes, I have a PySpark Dataframe that I need to cast two columns into 
a new column that is a list of tuples based the value of a third column. This cast will reduce or
flatten the dataframe by a key value, product id in this case, and the result os one row
per key.

There are hundreds of millions of rows in this dataframe, with 37M unique product ids. Therefore I need
a way to do the transformation on the spark cluster without bringing back any data
to the driver (Jupyter in this case).

Here is an extract of my dataframe for just 1 product:

```
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+--------+----------+---------------+
| product_id|      purchase_date|days_warranty|store_id|year_month|       category|
+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------+
|02147465400|2017-05-16 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2017-05|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2017-04-15 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2017-04|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2018-07-11 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2018-07|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2017-06-14 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2017-06|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2017-03-16 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2017-03|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2017-08-14 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2017-08|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2017-09-12 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2017-09|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2017-01-21 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2017-01|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2018-08-14 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2018-08|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2018-08-23 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2018-08|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2017-10-11 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2017-10|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2017-12-12 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2017-12|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2017-02-15 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2017-02|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2018-04-12 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2018-04|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2018-03-12 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2018-03|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2018-05-15 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2018-05|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2018-02-12 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2018-02|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2018-06-14 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2018-06|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2018-01-11 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2018-01|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2017-07-20 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2017-07|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2017-11-11 00:00:00|           30|     205|   2017-11|     CATEGORY A|
|02147465400|2017-01-05 00:00:00|           90|     205|   2017-01|     CATEGORY B|
|02147465400|2017-01-21 00:00:00|           90|     205|   2017-01|     CATEGORY B|
|02147465400|2017-10-09 00:00:00|           90|     205|   2017-10|     CATEGORY B|
|02147465400|2018-07-11 00:00:00|           90|     205|   2018-07|     CATEGORY B|
|02147465400|2017-04-16 00:00:00|           90|     205|   2017-04|     CATEGORY B|
|02147465400|2018-09-16 00:00:00|           90|     205|   2018-09|     CATEGORY B|
|02147465400|2018-04-14 00:00:00|           90|     205|   2018-04|     CATEGORY B|
|02147465400|2018-01-12 00:00:00|           90|     205|   2018-01|     CATEGORY B|
|02147465400|2017-07-15 00:00:00|           90|     205|   2017-07|     CATEGORY B|
+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

Here is the desired resulting dataframe, one row for the one product, where the rows
of the original dataframe have the purchase_date and days_warranty columns cast
as an array of tuples into new columns based on the category column value:

```
+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| product_id|                  CATEGORY A|                  CATEGORY B| 
+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|02147465400| [ (2017-05-16 00:00:00,30),| [ (2017-01-05 00:00:00,90),| 
|           |   (2017-04-15 00:00:00,30),|   (2017-01-21 00:00:00,90),|
|           |   (2018-07-11 00:00:00,30),|   (2017-10-09 00:00:00,90),|
|           |   (2017-06-14 00:00:00,30),|   (2018-07-11 00:00:00,90),|
|           |   (2017-03-16 00:00:00,30),|   (2017-04-16 00:00:00,90),|
|           |   (2017-08-14 00:00:00,30),|   (2018-09-16 00:00:00,90),|
|           |   (2017-09-12 00:00:00,30),|   (2018-04-14 00:00:00,90),|
|           |   (2017-01-21 00:00:00,30),|   (2018-01-12 00:00:00,90),|
|           |   (2018-08-14 00:00:00,30),|   (2017-07-15 00:00:00,90) |
|           |   (2018-08-23 00:00:00,30),| ]                          |
|           |   (2017-10-11 00:00:00,30),|                            |
|           |   (2017-12-12 00:00:00,30),|                            |
|           |   (2017-02-15 00:00:00,30),|                            |
|           |   (2018-04-12 00:00:00,30),|                            |
|           |   (2018-03-12 00:00:00,30),|                            |
|           |   (2018-05-15 00:00:00,30),|                            |
|           |   (2018-02-12 00:00:00,30),|                            |
|           |   (2018-06-14 00:00:00,30),|                            |
|           |   (2018-01-11 00:00:00,30),|                            |
|           |   (2017-07-20 00:00:00,30) |                            |
|           | ]                                                       |
+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `Dataframe` is called `df`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

gdf = (df.select("product_id", "category", struct("purchase_date", "warranty_days").alias("pd_wd"))
.groupBy("product_id")
.pivot("category")
.agg(collect_list("pd_wd")))
```

Essentially, you have to group the `purchase_date` and `warranty_days` into a single column using `struct()`. Then, you are just grouping by `product_id`, pivoting by `category`, can aggregating as `collect_list()`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `pivot` is an expensive operation so this may be really slow or could cause OOM error.

Comment: Certainly. It'd be interesting to see a benchmark of this method compared with a `.flatMap().groupBy().agg(collect_list())`. Also of note, `.pivot()` is more flexible, in case the number of distinct categories changes in the future.

Comment: I have validated this solution works in my environment. Thank you @Travis Hegner! Before I mark this complete, I like to test on my HUGE dataset and determine if I get acceptable performance. I have heard `groupBy()` is a heavyweight operation on compute.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you have performance issues with pivot the approach below is another solution to the same problem although it allows you to have more control by splitting the job into phases for each category with a for loop. For every iteration this will append the new data for the category_x into acc_df which will hold the accumulated results.

```
schema = ArrayType( 
        StructType((  
            StructField("p_date", StringType(), False), 
            StructField("d_warranty", StringType(), False)  
        )) 
    )

    tuple_list_udf = udf(tuple_list, schema)

    buf_size = 5 # if you get OOM error decrease this to persist more often

    categories = df.select("category").distinct().collect()

    acc_df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), df.schema) # create an empty df which holds the accumulated results for each category

    for idx, c in enumerate(categories):
        col_name = c[0].replace(" ", "_") # spark complains for columns containing space
        cat_df = df.where(df["category"] == c[0]) \
                .groupBy("product_id") \
                .agg(
                    F.collect_list(F.col("purchase_date")).alias("p_date"), 
                    F.collect_list(F.col("days_warranty")).alias("d_warranty")) \
                .withColumn(col_name, tuple_list_udf(F.col("p_date"), F.col("d_warranty"))) \
                .drop("p_date", "d_warranty")

        if idx == 0:
            acc_df = cat_df
        else:
            acc_df = acc_df \
                .join(cat_df.alias("cat_df"), "product_id") \
                .drop(F.col("cat_df.product_id"))

        # you can persist here every buf_size iterations
        if idx + 1 % buf_size == 0:
            acc_df = acc_df.persist()
```

The function tuple_list is responsible for generating a list with tuples from purchase_date and days_warranty columns.

```
def tuple_list(pdl, dwl):
    return list(zip(pdl, dwl))
```

The output of this will be:

```
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|product_id |CATEGORY_B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |CATEGORY_A                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|02147465400|[[2017-04-16 00:00:00, 90], [2018-09-16 00:00:00, 90], [2017-10-09 00:00:00, 90], [2018-01-12 00:00:00, 90], [2018-07-11 00:00:00, 90], [2017-01-21 00:00:00, 90], [2018-04-14 00:00:00, 90], [2017-01-05 00:00:00, 90], [2017-07-15 00:00:00, 90]]|[[2017-06-14 00:00:00, 30], [2018-08-14 00:00:00, 30], [2018-01-11 00:00:00, 30], [2018-04-12 00:00:00, 30], [2017-10-11 00:00:00, 30], [2017-05-16 00:00:00, 30], [2018-05-15 00:00:00, 30], [2017-04-15 00:00:00, 30], [2017-02-15 00:00:00, 30], [2018-02-12 00:00:00, 30], [2017-01-21 00:00:00, 30], [2018-07-11 00:00:00, 30], [2018-06-14 00:00:00, 30], [2017-03-16 00:00:00, 30], [2017-07-20 00:00:00, 30], [2018-08-23 00:00:00, 30], [2017-09-12 00:00:00, 30], [2018-03-12 00:00:00, 30], [2017-12-12 00:00:00, 30], [2017-08-14 00:00:00, 30], [2017-11-11 00:00:00, 30]]|
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Quite an efficient approach.