# Optimize multiple withColumn Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have to add multiple columns to a PySpark Dataframe, based on some conditions. Long story short, the code looks like this dumb example:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn('{}_without_otliers'.format(col), F.lit(1))
```

The problem is, when I have not so many columns (for example 15 or 20) it performs well, but when I have 100 columns it takes so long for spark to start the job, and the DAG looks huge. How can I optimize that ? Is there any way I can "force" spark to perform the operations every 10 columns ?

Comment: try considering `select` instead of looping through `withColumn`s: `df.select([F.lit(1).alias('{}_without_otliers'.format(col)) for col in df.columns])` . Although I don't think it'll have an impact on performance

Comment: Long story short, every N iteration save you accumulated dataframe as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167913/pyspark-dataframe-cast-two-columns-into-new-column-of-tuples-based-value-of-a-th/55265538#55265538). In this case I try to gain control over pivoting trying to split the operation but the logic should be the same. So 1. get col data 2. append it to big_df (it can be join as well) 3. save/persist it if `iteration % buffer_size == 0`